# MS Word - make page (or its content) static

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a page which contains a fullpage image with a caption. I need this page to be static so that text from the previous page will continue on the next page relative to this static page. Illustratively:

- `page 1` (text)
- `page 2` (fullpage image)
- `page 3` (text)

When on `page 1` there isn't enough space, text will continue on `page 3`.

I have tried to group the image and caption on `page 2` and make it "up and down" text wrapping (sorry I have Word in Czech language and don't know how it's named in English). That text wrapping option looks like this:
[image]
But it didn't work.

I have Microsoft Word 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this simply cannot be done. Word has a lot of options for controlling how and where an image is anchored, but when you do not want the image to hide text behind it (using the *In Front of Text* wrap option), **all of the anchors move when text on the prior page is moved to the image's page.**

Here are some of the strategies I've tried over the years to 
(unsuccessfully) solve this problem:

1. **Anchor the image in the page header.**  This works great if you want the image to be locked to the first page of a document because you can use the *Different first page* header option.  However, it's pointless because nobody is trying to add text before the first page.
2. **Anchor the image with absolute placement on the page**. This ensures the image never moves on the page on which it is placed, but if enough text is added before the page such that it intrudes upon the page in question, the entire image simply moves to the *next* page.
3. **Employ a Next Page Section Break.** It's at this point we realize we're desperate and out of options.  With a Section Break you can apply different page settings for a particular page and ensure text in the prior section cannot intrude on the new section, but again, when text in the prior section is moved down into the page with the image, Word simply moves the image (and the section's start point) to the next page.

Word is a good document editor, but it's not meant for desktop publishing.  Programs like Microsoft Publisher or Adobe PageMaker are better suited to requirements such as this one and include features that handle these tasks much better than Word.

Comment: Thanks. I don't write large documents/publications too often (this is my second larger publication - diploma thesis) so I haven't had need for another software than Word yet. This is the first problem I am encountering with Word. I will try the solutions you kindly provided and if no one works, I will reformat the document just before printing.

Comment: Just to clarify, the "solutions" I mentioned are things I've tried *unsuccessfully* to solve this issue.  I included them for the benefit of others who might suggest these solutions not realizing they don't solve your problem.